# Problem with importing bitcoin library in python

Tags: python, macos, import, bitcoin

Today I've run into problems trying to use the python-bitcoinlib in a small python program. It worked perfectly a few days ago but today the library seems to be broken (see console output below).

I'm in a Mac with OS X 11.0.1 (yes, I upgraded today, but I would be surprised if that's the cause of the problem).

I've tried several times installing and uninstalling the library and even python, but nothing seems to happen.

Thanks in advance.

```
>>> from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
        from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 48, in <module>
        from bitcoin.wallet import CBitcoinAddress, CBitcoinSecret
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bitcoin/wallet.py", line 33, in <module>
        import bitcoin.core.key
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bitcoin/core/key.py", line 34, in <module>
        _ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or 'libeay32')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
        return self._dlltype(name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: dlopen(libeay32, 6): image not found
```

Comment: Hmm, this one's tough. There hasn't been an update to this library in a while; library issues are always frustrating. Specifically, what version of Python and Bitcoin Core are you using?

Comment: Hi. I'm using python3.9 and the latest Bitcoin Core. The problem is that a few days ago it worked. I was trying to do the small code exercises in Antonopoulos bitcoin book, so this is a bit frustrating.

Comment: Bitcoin core is v0.20.1

Comment: It seems to me that RawProxy is broken. For doing something similar (it seems) it would be better to use '''from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy'''

Comment: actually I've upgraded a couple of days ago and came back at working at a project which was working before the update, so yea, it matches my experience, yay Mac OS. I'll come back if I find a fix

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not using RawProxy.

Impor this instead:

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy
```

And connect to bitcoin core with this sentence or equivalent:

```
p = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332"%(rpcuser, rpcpassword))
```